# How do you uninstall wine 1.5?

Tags: wine, uninstall

I installed Wine through the terminal using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```

I know that I've removed at least part of wine. I removed the .wine folder in my home folder and I managed to remove the repository via this command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Now when I try to install wine 1.4 via Ubuntu software center, it tells me I must remove these items to install wine:

> Microsoft windows compatibility layer (binary emulator and library)
>   wine1.5
>
> Microsoft windows compatibility layer (64-bit support)
>   wine1.5-amd64
>
> Microsoft windows compatibility layer (32-bit support)
>   wine1.5-i386:i386

I've already tried this command:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove wine`

but it said that wine wasn't installed. Some assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: **CAREFUL** with that first answer " (Use this command:sudo apt-get purge wine backslash *) " It has erased most of my system files forcing me to backup my documents and reinstall Ubuntu... I Wish I had read the other users' warnings before doing something like that.

Comment: As @user169362 says, proposed solutions that have `*` in a package name are usually wrong and dangerous, even if it is quoted or preceded by ``\``. See [Why does apt removes unwanted packages when giving * as suffix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431604/why-does-apt-removes-unwanted-packages-when-giving-as-suffix) and [How to fix Ubuntu after accidentally uninstalling many packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249367/how-to-fix-ubuntu-after-accidentally-uninstalling-many-packages)

Answer (score 8):

You can use a the ppa-purge utility to remove any packages installed by a ppa and downgrade any packages that were upgraded by the ppa.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Comment: That's should be marked as answer, because it will remove everything including wine ppa. So you can start from scratch,

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and can't believe I didn't think of this faster.
Use the following:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove wine1.5
```

Just add the 1.5 and the end of wine =) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
sudo apt-get remove wine1.5
```