# Ubuntu system is broken after accidentally uninstalling many packages

Tags: apt, reinstall

I accidentally removed all the packages starting with the name `jpeg` with:

```
sudo apt-get remove jpeg*
```

This screwed up a lot of things, removed Unity, Firefox, Flash player etc.

I somehow managed to recover the desktop and unity but then a lot of things are still buggy. For example `.rpm` files and `.tag.gz` just won't open up at all.

What I want is a way to fix everything that's amiss. Something that is the equivalent of a 'repair installation' with a windows disc.

Any tips, anyone?

Comment: I'd really recommend a fresh install. Just backup your /home/ (including invisible files) and insert it in the new installation.

Comment: Related: [Why does apt removes unwanted packages when giving * as suffix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431604/why-does-apt-removes-unwanted-packages-when-giving-as-suffix)

Comment: I don't mean to be patronising, but my tip is to _read confirmation messages_. `apt-get` will tell you what it plans to un/install and _ask_ you if that's OK. I get that maybe we're used to just saying 'yeah whatever' because of excessive confirmations in other contexts, but Linux is pretty good about not asking frivolously, and package-management is not a context where you should default to having your guard down.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can install the `ubuntu-desktop` task:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^
```

This will install all the packages of the standard Ubuntu Desktop you have removed. It won't restore packages you had installed that are not part of the standard desktop (i.e. it will reinstall Unity and Firefox, but not Flash player).

To install those packages, you can look into `/var/log/apt/history.log` and see exactly what you had removed.

**Note:** installing the `ubuntu-desktop^` *task* is not the same as installing the `ubuntu-desktop` *package*. The first will give APT some hints to resolve dependencies involving virtual packages, the latter will give APT the freedom to choose packages (and will end up installing useless stuff like `ubiquity`).

**Why has the problem happened?** `apt-get remove jpeg*` will **not** remove all packages starting with `jpeg`. It will instead remove all packages containing `jpe` in their name. This is because apt-get works with regular expression, so that *jpeg** means: everything containing *jpe* followed by zero or more *g*.

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't thought of that. I'll be interested to see if it will work here!

Comment: @EliahKagan: I've tested in a chroot. jpeg* packages only affect some graphical applications, so the necessary 'ingredients' (i.e. NetworkManager for Internet connectivity, APT, terminal emulators and so on) are still on the OP system.

Comment: @EliahKagan: of course, I made the (non-obvious) assumption that the OP hasn't removed anything else.

Comment: Please include a warning to **never** use `tasksel` to remove a task - see [nasty tasksel-bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/574287)

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: which is the difference between "sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^" with and without the "^" ?

Comment: @Attilio: I have explained the difference in the answer. See *"Note: installing the ubuntu-desktop^ task is not the same as installing the ubuntu-desktop package ..."*

Answer (score 13):

The best way for you to fix this problem might be to reinstall Ubuntu. (You should back up your documents first, even if you plan to reinstall without reformatting.)

If you do want to try to fix the system in place, then look at the package manager's log files to see what packages were removed, and reinstall them:

- `/var/log/dpkg.log` (full information, but hard to read)
- `/var/log/apt/history.log` (abbreviated by will tell you every package removed or otherwise modified - likely your best bet)
- `/var/log/apt/term.log` (if you removed the packages with `apt-get` in the terminal, this should show what you saw then, including lists of what packages were going to be removed - so this *might* be the best way)

Reinstalling just packages whose names start with `jpeg` won't work, because many (almost certainly most) of the packages that were removed were removed because they *relied on* those packages.

**In the future**, I recommend carefully checking the consequences of uninstalling a package. If you're working from the command-line, you'll always be notified. (Unless you use the `-y` option, in which case, usually not. I recommend against using that option unless you know what you're doing, especially for removals.)

One way to check the consequences of a package management operation carried out with `apt-get`, without risking them happening, is to run `apt-get -s` instead of `sudo apt-get`. This merely simulates the action specified, and reports what packages are would be affected as a result and how.

Answer (score 1):

I run `sudo apt-get purge wine*` on Ubuntu 15.10, so no graphical interface on boot only terminal login option.

As Eliah Kagan suggested I used info from `/var/log/apt/history.log`
I run nano on history.log and made a simple script that contained `sudo apt-get install` on all purged packages I found at line :

```
Purge: evolution:amd64 (3.16.5-1ubuntu3.1), libtotem-plparser18:amd64 (3.10.5-1) ...... etc
```

But first I had manually to remove text between all : and ,
including the : ,

at this step a new script would be helpful because the packages were hundreds.
after that I run the script and removed a few `Unable to locate packages` (which I had manually installed).
run the script again and thats it. Everything is working fine ... luckily

Answer (score 0):

Install the [ubuntu-desktop [image: Install ubuntu-desktop]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-desktop) package

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

It will install necessary packages for your system.

Comment: this fails for me since the dependencies of ubuntu-desktop are not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small python script where you can write the (unusable) package string from your mass uninstall that is on `/var/log/apt/history.log`. It will output a string that you can copy paste into the apt-get install command in order to easily install all the removed packages.

```
import re

apt_str = u"INSERT YOUR PACKAGE STRING HERE, BETWEEN THE QUOTES"

match =  re.findall(r'([\w\d\.-]+).+? \(.+?\)', apt_str)
print " ".join(match)
```

Comment: Commas? Do you mean quotes?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes I mean quotes

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally removed `libssl1.0.0` and my machine was crippled. To restore, I did:

1. Backup the logs of what was removed `cp /var/log/apt/term.log ~/libssl.term.log`
2. Delete the lines unrelated to the libssl action `vi ~/libssl.term.log`
3. If networking is missing (can't `ping google.com`), then reboot in recovery mode and enable networking
4. Reinstall removed packages `cat ~/libssl.term.log | grep ^Removing | sed -e 's/^Removing //g;s/ (.*$//g;/diversion of/d;/dangling symlinks/d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y install`