# apt-get broken + dependencies issue + many software uninstalled

Tags: apt, package-management

OS=ubuntu 12.04 64bit 3.2.0-29-generic

what i did?

apt-get purge libre*
which i thought will remove LO 3.5 but, which was a big mistake after couple of moments, i realise that its is removing all other software so i did cltl-c which stopped the apt process i restarted my system after that i found that following software were missing apt-get,evince(pdf), cheese etc..here is full list http://pastebin.com/CWHrw10y

i managed to install APT deb file through dpkg but now i am not able to do any installation so i just removed /var/lib/dpkg/status and created new but that didnt help

```
apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apt-utils coreutils debconf debconf-i18n dpkg libacl1 libapt-inst1.4
  libapt-pkg4.12 libattr1 libbz2-1.0 libdb5.1 libgcc1 liblocale-gettext-perl
  liblzma5 libselinux1 libstdc++6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libtext-wrapi18n-perl perl-base tar tzdata xz-utils zlib1g
Suggested packages:
  debconf-doc debconf-utils whiptail dialog gnome-utils
  libterm-readline-gnu-perl libgtk2-perl libnet-ldap-perl libqtgui4-perl
  libqtcore4-perl apt bzip2 ncompress xz-lzma
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-utils coreutils debconf debconf-i18n dpkg libacl1 libapt-inst1.4
  libapt-pkg4.12 libattr1 libbz2-1.0 libdb5.1 libgcc1 liblocale-gettext-perl
  liblzma5 libselinux1 libstdc++6 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libtext-wrapi18n-perl perl-base tar tzdata xz-utils zlib1g
0 upgraded, 24 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,246 kB of archives.
After this operation, 29.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
E: Cannot get debconf version. Is debconf installed?
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg: regarding .../libgcc1_1%3a4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb containing libgcc1, pre-dependency problem:
 libgcc1 pre-depends on multiarch-support
  multiarch-support is unpacked, but has never been configured.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing libgcc1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgcc1_1%3a4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
E: Internal Error, No file name for libc6
W: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'multiarch-support:amd64'. Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
# apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Depends: libgcc1 but it is not installed
         Depends: tzdata but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

i have tried below link 
["debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/unable-to-install-due-to-debconf-problem)
[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)
but no help...

thanks

Comment: libgcc1_1%3a4.6.3-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb  tzdata_2012b-1_all.deb i tried to install but that didn't help can you tell how do i do install-repair  i am having live usb.

Comment: Read: http://askubuntu.com/questions/249367/how-to-fix-ubuntu-after-accidentally-uninstalling-many-packages

Comment: thanks david for reply but i cannot do anything with apt-get i think i might have to reinstall which i don't want to do

Comment: ok got that !! what is your say on re-installing and choosing "Something Else" option when installing and not formatting partition  will it preserve my data on partition(/home).

Comment: **No.** ***Read the other question more carefully.*** *You need to re-install Ubuntu, and you need your data backed-up first.*