# I uninstalled Python without realizing it's really important. What should I do?

Tags: python

How much have I broken and should I just reinstall the OS?

Comment: You could try to restart your computer in recovery mode and use the following command to install all default packages again: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: How do I get networking working in recovery mode?

Comment: Got that working actually. Are you sure that is all I need to install?

Comment: It should install all default packages, so that'll do it.

Comment: So, anyone can gain root access to another person's computer by starting in recovery mode?

Comment: @michaelAdam Yep. There are quite a few questions about that here. Options range from the nuclear option: use full-disk encryption to the ziplock on the bag: set the root password.

Comment: @muru not that having a root PW set would change a lot - attacker just boots from a media of her own - which she probably would have done anyway :-)

Comment: If you find a solution, please answer your own question, as a favor for future users.

Comment: @guntbert which is why I said "ziplock on a bag". Let's please, please, please not go down that road.

Comment: @muru I definitely won't go that road **now** - but your statement could be read as recommendation for ...

Comment: At everybody: Can you not see me mentioning full-disk-encryption? Nothing short of that is going to stop determined hackers, and maybe not even that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my real question, uninstalling Python entirely broke the desktop.  I was not even able to open text-only mode. I'm not sure how it remained functional for a while; maybe everything was cached.  It is *not* necessary to reinstall the OS.

Following the advice of Timo, I booted in recovery mode following instructions in this tutorial: [RecoveryMode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).  I enabled networking before opening the root shell.  I was not able to get online over wifi; I had to use ethernet.  Then I ran

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

Now my desktop is fixed!

Comment: Installing the task rather than the (meta)package [might work even better.](http://askubuntu.com/a/249373/22949)