# Trying to Install Pip using python-pip

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation, python

Was trying to install Pip through the command

I was getting the following error message.

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
.....
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Also as stated in the terminal tried using the command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Which gave this in return

```
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
.....
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

As Suggested in some threads I tried using `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install samba`
 but didnt work. I also tried removing the individual package but this failed as well. 
I have both python 2.7 as well 3.5.1 installed.

My `python -V` returns `Python 2.7.6`.

My `python3 -V` returns `Python 3.5.1`.

My `apt-cache policy python python3` returns

```
python:
  Installed: 3.5.1-1
  Candidate: 3.5.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.1-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
python3:
  Installed: 3.4.0-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.4.0-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

After using `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo add-apt-repository main; apt-cache policy python`

```
python:
  Installed: 3.5.1-1
  Candidate: 3.5.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.1-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.5-5ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show me the output of `python -V ; python3 -V ; apt-cache policy python python3`. Make sure you [edit] your question to provide it, because comments don't preserve formatting. Thanks!

Comment: This is strange, did you modify the output of `apt-cache policy python` and remove some lines? Please run `sudo add-apt-repository main && sudo apt-get update && apt-cache policy python` and add the output to your question again. The package `python` must provide a Python version 2.7, not 3.5. I wonder why you don't see any installation candidates except the cached one.

Comment: I didnt do anything to modify the code. The command you mentioned returned `hive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
python:
  Installed: 3.5.1-1
  Candidate: 3.5.1-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.5.1-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`

Comment: Please run `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo add-apt-repository main`. Any errors? What output does `apt-cache policy python` give you now? (And still: [edit] your question. Comments have ugly formatting)

Comment: Okay, that looks good. Now you can downgrade the `python` package to the required 2.7.5-5 using `sudo apt-get install python=2.7.5-5ubuntu3`. Please run that and `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and finally try your original commands again afterwards. Tell me if it worked and I'll convert these comments into an answer.

Comment: Sorry I ended up crashing the office machine. Couldn't reply from there. apt-get -f install removed all dependent packages and computer refused to start.

Comment: Can you upload the content of you file `/var/log/apt/history.log` to e.g. https://www.pastebin.com and give me the link? That way we can find out which packages exactly got removed and reinstall them manually in the correct version.

Comment: Currently I'm at home will do so as soon as I reach office tomorrow.. Thanks a million

Comment: What might also help to recover your packages is this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/249367/367990

Comment: Hello here is the pastebin link you requested [http://pastebin.com/kWaZkUGN]

Comment: Kinda got back the important packages using `apt-get install --reinstall gdm; 
dpkg-reconfigure gdm;
apt-get install --reinstall gnome;
`  now tring to reinstall additional packages. Also the pip issue has been solved thanks a ton.  how do i flag as resolved

Comment: As you managed to resolve the uninstalled packages yourself, I don't really need the pastebin any more. But to mark a question as solved, you accept an answer by clicking the grey tick symbol on the left of it. I've converted my comments into an answer for you. Oh, and make sure you have read our little [tour] page to learn the most important things about how this site works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `apt-cache policy python` output told me that you could not install the correct `python` version (2.7.x) from the repositories. As Python is located in the `main` repository, we should first try to activate that repository (again) and update the package lists:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo apt-get update
```

As you got an *invalid signature (BADSIG)* error, we completely remove all package lists and re-download them. Also in case the error prevented it from working, we try to enable the `main` repository again.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo apt-get update
```

Now the new `apt-cache policy python` output shows the correct version available from the server, so we can now force the downgrade of our package `python` to the required version:

```
sudo apt-get install python=2.7.5-5ubuntu3
```

We then need to clean the locally cached wrong 3.5 version and just empty the entire package cache therefore:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then we let it try to upgrade all remaining packages and hope for the best:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

**The basic steps are:**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now that the package lists have been updated we can upgrade to the latest versions with the apt-get upgrade command:

```
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

Once the packages have been upgraded, we can install Python 3.7. This is done with the apt-get install command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3.7
```

Once the installation is complete, we confirm that it was successful by calling Python 3.7 and printing out the version number:

```
python3.7 -V

# expected output
Python 3.7.3
```

Now we have successfully completed the installation of Python. Since we want to work with other Python packages in the future, we can now install the package management program PIP. For this we execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

In the following, we make sure that Python 3.7 is the latest python3 version. To achieve that we set a symbolic link to python3.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3
```

Once PIP has been installed we have to update PIP. Unfortunately we have to do this manually although we have just installed PIP, cause the installed version is pretty old, so yes, this step is necessary:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Once the installation is complete we also confirm this by calling the version number of PIP:

```
python3 -m pip -V

# expected output
pip 19.2.1 from /home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Now we are still testing if we can actually install libraries with PIP. For this we use a very popular Python math library named numpy

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

**For the full video and text source go here:**
[Video Source](https://youtu.be/PKUrhVqEpxE)
[Text Source](https://techdiffuse.com/en/2019/08/06/python-how-to-install/)