# Purging libglew1.13 broke Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I'm on the latest Ubuntu distro (Xenial?) and was installing libglew1.10. Before doing so I wanted to get rid of 1.13 so they didn't clash. However after running a apt-get purge libglew1.13, and restarting the PC, many things aren't showing up correctly. I imagine this is due to removing other dependencies with it...

Could someone please tell me how to fix this? I can reinstall packages again via the terminal. If someone does a sudo apt-get purge libglew1.13 (without pressing Y so it goes through with it), it'll say which dependencies were purged.

Or, if someone has a simpler way to repair the broken dependencies/packages, I'm all ears.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Ubuntu after accidentally uninstalling many packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/249367/how-to-fix-ubuntu-after-accidentally-uninstalling-many-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` seemed to fix the issue!