# "Couldn't find support for device", cannot log in or access network after removing python2.7

Tags: 14.04, boot, python, gnome-terminal

I accidentally removed python2.7 so most of things disappeared like all bars and I couldn't use terminal.

After searching to try to solve it like install `ubuntu-desktop` then after restarting the machine, I still only see the Ubuntu logo and can't reach the login screen

I'm not able to access the wireless network.

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you remove python2.7?

Comment: Apt-get remove python . I had 2 versions so I deleted them to install them from scratch and didn't know that python2 is important for Ubuntu

Comment: At what point in the boot process does it fail? Do you get to the login screen at least?

Comment: I restarted the machine and got logo of Ubuntu only .. the only thing that I can use it grub

Comment: The problem is different .. I couldn't access any terminal window to write the commands

Comment: I couldn't access the network so I couldn't install any packages

Comment: I just edited my comment to clarify

Comment: I edited with screenshot of what I got when enabled network

Comment: It looks like https://askubuntu.com/a/249372/175814 might be the most suitable solution here. (pinging @Fabby)

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yeah, looks like it, but I cannot remember the way I voted.  Can a mod edit the other dupe out?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a text-only virtual console by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Reinstall Python by running the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install python-all python3-all
   ```
5. Switch out of the virtual console and return to your desktop environment by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

---

After you have installed Python, you need to get back your default Unity desktop. In order to avoid messing something up, do it in the following order:

1. First install the terminal from the console using the command: `sudo apt install gnome-terminal`. If you can't install gnome-terminal at all, skip this step and go to step 2.
2. Return to your desktop and open the terminal using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. From the terminal install the Ubuntu Software Center using the command:

   ```
   sudo apt install software-center
   ```

   If you still can't open the terminal, run the same command from the console instead. If you can't install the default software application at all, skip this step and go to step 3.
3. Open the terminal and try to open the Ubuntu Software Center from the terminal by running the `software-center` command. From the Ubuntu Software Center install the Ubuntu desktop system or else open the terminal (or the console) and install the Ubuntu desktop system by running this command:

   ```
   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
   ```

Comment: Thanks for helping but first command didn't work .. still logo of Ubuntu exist

Comment: This problem because I remove python before that it was work fine