# accidentally removed a lot of libraries

Tags: system-installation, libraries, software-uninstall, openssl

I installed multiple versions of openssl (because mysqlconnectorcame with them), but that broke cmake, so I tried re-installing openssl with `sudo apt-get remove openssl`. However, that apparently removed a **lot** of dependencies. Can I get these back without reinstalling my operating system? Do I have to re-install them one by one (there are nearly a hundred it looks like)?

Comment: Faster to reinstall your OS.  Removing OpenSSL basically cripples your system for anything SSL-related, so it'd be a lesson in self-punishment to try and reinstall everything one by one.

Comment: @ThomasWard I have some work I need to back up so taking that into account, it might be the only option. I'm trying to drag and drop things into dropbox, but my file viewer isn't even working.

Comment: There's a lesson here about carefully reading apt's proposed actions before agreeing. That prompt really is there to protect you.

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu system is broken after accidentally uninstalling many packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249367/ubuntu-system-is-broken-after-accidentally-uninstalling-many-packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to check history and get results of apt related operations you did using command line by `history | grep -i apt` command and check at which point or command you purged all libraries. You can do installation of same packages you purged.

Example:

If `sudo apt purge openssl` command removed your libraries then you can re-install it by `sudo apt install openssl` command.

By that way it will install all libraries and dependencies automatically which you purged.

Comment: what is reverse action? This sounds like an "undo" button

Comment: There is also `/var/log/apt/history.log` for all `apt`-related commands.

Comment: +1 for searching history. Perhaps a short intro for grep `sudo apt` on `~/.bash_history` might be needed though.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see serious problems here.

You should login onto the first text terminal (accessible with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and then install software from here.

Carefully read the contents of APT log-files with `more /var/log/apt/history.log` and `more /var/log/apt/term.log` and then install removed packages manually with something like:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install removed-app-name
```

If your desktop was removed too, then use something like:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^ # if you had Ubuntu GNOME desktop
#sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop # if you had Ubuntu Unity desktop
#sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop^ # if you had Kubuntu
#sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop^ # if you had Ubuntu with MATE DE
```

Comment: do I have to reinstall them one by one? what is the relationship between `ubuntu-desktop` and all of these packages?

Comment: It depends on desktop environment. You need to install one package. If you had GNOME - then it would be  `ubuntu-desktop^`, for KDE use `kubuntu-desktop^` and so on. When you get desktop reinstalled then look into `history.log` and install other packages.

Comment: you're saying I don't need to install all of these packages. I don't understand that. I understand that there are different desktops. I just don't know why you're bringing this up, how this fixes my problem, or how it answers my original question.

Comment: Then it depends on what do you mean by "removed a **lot** of dependencies." Was your desktop removed? I suppose that it is broken as you wrote "my file viewer isn't even working"...

Answer (score 0):

The "Diagnose, Understand, then Fix" method **must** be done in this order. **Must!**

"... broke `cmake`"?

You can find the names of the uninstalled packages in `/var/log/apt`.