# How to remove wine-1.7.34 completely

Tags: 14.04, wine, uninstall, winetricks

I have tried a lot of different commands, but nothing helped.

```
    sudo apt-get remove wine --purge
    sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
    sudo apt-get auto remove
```

Wine is still available. Wine version is wine-1.7.34.
Please help, how can I remove wine completely including installed windows programs and winetricks.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy wine ` and `command -v wine`

Comment: autoremove has done the trick for me

Answer (score 6):

For me, wine was installed as multiple packages with different versions - for example `wine1.4` or `wine1.4-i386`.

To remove all of them, I simply typed `sudo apt-get purge wine` and then pressed <kbd>TAB</kbd> to display all installed packages with name starting with 'wine' and removed all of them. Of course, `sudo apt-get autoremove` was necessary at the end to clean unneeded pacakges.

Note: Be careful with `sudo apt-get purge wine*`, it can remove more than you really want! - see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446651/apt-get-remove-purge-wine-removed-everything) for more info.

Comment: You saved My day(or night)!! thanks , I was looking for this everywhere bro!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

`sudo apt-get purge wine*`

This will remove every single package related to wine.
This is probably because there are more than one package for wine in the repositories.

Comment: doesn't work I have already tried

Comment: *Don't do this!* See [Why does apt removes unwanted packages when giving * as suffix?](https://askubuntu.com/q/431604) The `purge` or `remove` action with an argument like `wine*`, `wine\*`, or `'wine*'` removes way more than you might think. It removes every package with `win` anywhere in its name (not `wine`, `win`--as `wine*` is treated as a regex and `e*` means "zero or more `e`s") and every package that depends directly or indirectly on any of those packages. This often breaks an Ubuntu system very badly, preventing it from being used for much of anything until it is fixed or reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Ok，I think you should make sure to install it by using `apt-get install wine` rather than other ways. So I think you can remove wine by your comman, if you used `apt-get install wine` command to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Dash board (the topmost icon). 
Type in 'wine' in the search box.
Then with the wine application; 'uninstall wine' will also pop up.
Just click on it, and follow the process!