# Accidentally removed Ubuntu applications

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, software-center

I've been trying to open a .exe file.

I downloaded `wine` to do so, then ended up trying to remove it.

Upon removing `wine`, I somehow removed a LOT of other things. For example:

- I can no longer use the "Search your computer and online sources."
- I can't access the `Ubuntu software center`

I also get an error when I do `sudo apt-get update`.

Console Output:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
```

EDIT:
I'm using a chromebook, and I can switch between ChromeOS and Ubuntu. Now whenever I go to the Ubuntu, it completely crashes. I believe the damage is beyond repair now.

Answer (score -1):

As seen in a [duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/a/446662/280601):

> Run the command again, however, this time run the command
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge wine
> ```
>
> ... you should take note of the list of programs that will be uninstalled along with wine so you may reinstall these programs after the purge and before the next reboot.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work. The damage is much deeper.